# Currency Fomat in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app where I have to show currency in below format

```
$ 222,345.00   (Symbole depends on location/country. May be $,R etc)
```

I am trying to set using below code

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency

    if let formattedTipAmount = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:amountDouble)) {
       self.amountLabel.text= "\(formattedTipAmount)"
    }
```

Above code add correct currency symbol but for some country above code added ',' as decimal point & also there is no ',' seprater if there is huge amount.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: In some countries (such as Germany), the comma *is* the decimal separator, and no grouping separator is used by default. – So most probably, you are doing nothing wrong.

Comment: @MartinR yes but the requirement is to add . for the decimal separator and , for number separater

Comment: Then set the corresponding properties of the NumberFormatter. It can all be configured.

Comment: @MartinR can you please explain if possible.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Your requirement is a bad one. It's going confuse most users of your app. Please convince whoever made the decision that they need to reconsider their choice. Let `NumberFormatter` do its job and show the currency in the expected format for the user's locale.

Comment: @rmaddy I disagree, at least for some scenarios, since for example I think it would be confusing if I had a column in a table with amounts and the format changed from row to row depending on the currency.  It would be very difficult to read.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't suggest that at all. All the currencies would be formatted the same but that formatting should be based on the viewer's locale, not some hardcode locale chosen by some manager that doesn't understand localization.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so the behaviour of the ',' for some locations (think almost all of Europe) is correct. To make sure that the big numbers also have a separator (which would be a . in Europe) you have to add the `usesGroupSeperator` attribute of the `NumberFormatter`. So to make this work with your code you would need to change it to the following:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

if let formattedTipAmount = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:amountDouble)) {
   self.amountLabel.text= "\(formattedTipAmount)"
}
```

however if you want to change the grouping separator and the decimal separator you can do this by adding the following 2 attributes to your code. Where the `GroupingSeparator` is used to change the separator for big numbers and the `DecimalSeparator` is used for the separator regarding the decimals.

```
formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = ","
formatter.currencyDecimalSeparator = "."
```

Comment: Don't change the grouping or decimal separators. This will result in very confusing output for many people around the world.

Comment: Im not saying he should do it but since there was talk about it in the comments I figured I would tell him that it is possible and how you could achieve it. I absolutely dont advice it though